# Страница со своими новостями на сайте

Tags: веб-дизайн

Прошу прощения, возможно вопрос является откровенно идиотским, но он мне никак не дает покоя.

Итак, как **"правильно"** сделать блок с новостями проекта? Вот я сейчас занимаюсь таким сайтом: http://sdro.meximas.com/ У меня на главной будут новости. Через некоторое время их будет достаточно много. Неправильно ведь делать так, чтобы они все сразу за 10 лет отображались на одной странице. Как быть? Как реализовать? Может быть есть какие-нибудь готовые решения?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Есть много вариантов реализации в зависимости от языка, фреймворка и т.д.
Например, если новости хранятся в **БД** и мы используем **MySQL** и **php**, то из php посылаем SQL запрос к БД с количеством новостей, которые нужно вернуть или с ограничением по дате (последний месяц, последняя неделя и т.д.), БД возвращает информацию, и мы выводим информацию с помощью php в том виде, котором ходим. Можем хранить новости прямо в файле(например, в **XML** или **JSON** формате) и средствами **JavaScript** получать информацию из этих файлов, обрабатывать и выводить...В общем, все зависит от твоих предпочтений и знаний.